# Zutritt verboten

Tags: word-usage

When I was in Germany, I saw many signs saying

> Zutritt verboten.

I understand what it means, but why do they write it this way instead of

> Dir ist nicht erlaubt eintreten!

or something similar?

Is “Zutritt verboten” the same? So, if I want to express the flight attendant must not enter the cockpit, can I also write it as: “Der Flugbegleiter ist Zutritt verboten in das Cockpit”?

Comment: Weird translations for "flight attendant" and "cockpit". Where did you dig those out? Whatever your source was, throw it away. I fixed these words; however I leave the grammatical mistakes to be addressed in answers.

Comment: A sign should, whenever possible, be understood immediately. So, it has to be short, reduced to the relevant piece of information.

Comment: Have you ever seen an official sign stating "You are not allowed to park here"? No, it says "Parking prohibited", or maybe even "No parking".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will never see an official sign in Germany that reads "You are not allowed to...". Official signs are never personal, they don't have words like *he*, *she*, *I*, *you* etc. "Zutritt verboten" is short, easy to remember and does the trick.
If you would like to say it in a different, more personal way, I would suggest

> Du darfst hier nicht rein. (You are not allowed inside).

If we take the airplane scenario, you would use either of the following ways:

> Dem Flugbegleiter ist der Zutritt zum Cockpit verboten.
>
> Dem Flugbegleiter ist das Betreten des Cockpits verboten.

Comment: Ich weiß nicht warum du "das Betreten ist verboten" besser findest.  Es ginge doch auch "Dem Flugbegleiter ist der Zutritt zum Cockpit ist verboten"

Comment: This might just be me: But if saw a sign using "Du" I would ignore it on principle.  Using "Sie" would still confound me, but might work. However, a sign like this is intended to state a rule (something given and for the time being not up to debate) and thus there's no need to get personal.

Comment: @Iris, du hast natürlich Recht, ich habe den Eintrag editiert und erweitert

Comment: @Bort, no, it's not just you. In an official context a proscription with "Du" sounds strange. Staff would always say "Sie dürfen hier nicht rein!".  "Du" is only okay, if e.g. my roommate tells me not to enter her room.

Comment: IKEA is one company that say "Du" to anyone. However, IKEA doesn't forbit anything, but thanks you for not doing it, e.g. "Danke, dass du hier nicht rauchst".

Comment: @Bort Well, there is one "official sign", erm stone, that uses "Du". It's called "The Ten Commandments". ;)

Answer (score 3):

In general, all the signs (or *Zeichen*) have a short phrase or they are represented by a simple picture, because they have to be easily understood and remembered, for example by a person walking inside a building or someone driving on the street. For a human being, it's very easy to remember a picture and associate something to it (like a short phrase), but it's very difficult for him/her to remember something like *Der Zutritt ist hier verboten weil etc*.

*Zutritt verboten*  is just one example, but you can find something else like *Achtung!* (to pay attention) or *STOP* (to stop your vehicle), or *Rauchen verboten!* (no smoking). Take a look at [this page](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bildtafel_der_Verkehrszeichen_in_der_Bundesrepublik_Deutschland_seit_2013) for other examples.

Obviously, the official signs are designed in this way everywhere in the world, not in Germany only.